# How to fetch image inputstream in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```js
this my component.ts code

this.allMeta.getProfilePictureUsingMediaId({
           "SessionID": "dswesfgdgfdgf12463",
           "MACAddress":"1235874"
           "MediaID":this.userProfilePicture
         }).subscribe(
           data => {
             console.log(data);
             this.profilepic=data
             }
             );
             
  below is my service code,
  getProfilePictureUsingMediaId(pjson){
    return this.http.post(this.profile + 'getProfilePictureUsingMediaId', pjson)
    .map((data: any) => data.json());
  }
```

```html
<div style="height:240px" class="row">
                <img id="ItemPreview" [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+profilepic" />
            </div>
```

Below displaying data I am getting from server, how to make it visible same image in my web app, beacuse after calling server in service, i got data value undefiend.

```html
����JFIF��C
#%$""!&+7/&)4)!"0A149;>>>%.DIC
<H7=>;��C

;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;��"����=!1A"Qaq2B��#R�$���3b�Sr�����C����%!1AQ"a2���?B�vϚ���8���\J3��y�A�l9fv��k�<�H�R�{\n��&���T��q�k���h$Yau;�����p���x�������nN�q��RWcp����h�~f}�8#�$�&���$Tn;�6Is�X�"@C��n-ߦϳ��k8�c��)�V���b�Y�\p��Vҍ�fp�'I��S�.4%�Xx����9�S+F������|2D�F՗�d%�F��UlS��NkEL�VP
�0k�Lr�RRA'�]���禣`���DX��,Hc[�)nO�����i��Ow�sC��";9����-�é2�
```

Sorry I don't know how to send this data so I am using html to show u this picture and also it is not complete data.

Comment: Do not display bytes in paragraph but inside html tag as shown in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`<img id="ItemPreview" [src]="imageVariable" />` . in your html

and use an `imageVariable` in ts file like this

```
imageVariable="`data:image/png;base64,"+ yourBytestream
```

Here is a working solution:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cthpw)

Comment: No, its not working to me, if i add my data inside your code I am getting an error. May be my code not in byte code

Comment: I am getting huge data

Comment: what sort of data is it ? Can you share the bytes ?

Comment: Even I don't know, if i add complete data then i got an error in snippet, if i share it directly then its a too long string, stack overflow not allow to send entire data

Comment: May be my data is multipart data